# Loading an image in C#

Tags: c#, python, graphics

I 'm beginning C# programming and I want to make a simple program that loads an image and displays it in a window. Is there a standard way of doing it and/or a **simplest** way?

What I'm asking for is a counterpart (in simplicity and power) of Python's [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) module, a way of writing this

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

try:
    orig = Image.open("img.jpg")
    orig.show()
except:
    print "Unable to load image"
```

in C# (preferably in a console application as I'm still exploring the language)

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: The code you posted does not match your question.. Do you want to load and display an image, or load, blur and save an image?

Comment: I hope the edit has cleared my question

Answer (score 3):

Here's a minimal console application example using WinForms:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static void Main()
{   
    var image = new PictureBox();
    image.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;        
    image.Load(@"img.jpg");
    var f = new Form();
    f.Controls.Add(image);      
    Application.Run(f);
}
```

You'll have to add a project reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll; it won't be there by default in a console application.

It would be even easier of course, if you started with a Windows Forms project, used the form designer and dragged the picture box onto the form.